# PHP - Get text between <br> and <br>

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
item1<br>item2<br>item3<br>item4<br>item5
```

How can I get the text between each `<br>` and `<br>`? I tried with preg_match_all and the following regex but it doesn't show all the results.
    `` `<br>(.*)<br> `` `Usi

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your data really that regular?  If so, just `explode()` on `<br>`.

Comment: What about just exploding on <br>?  [Edit:  Curse you, Brad!  *shakes fist*]

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the input data is close to what you said, this will give you array with all the pieces in:

```
$pieces = explode('<br>', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

use explode with `<br>`

http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex solution.  `preg_match_all('/.*?(?=<br>)/', $string)`

Answer (score 0):

If your data follows that pattern, use the explode function ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)).

The code would look like this:

```
$html = "item1<br>item2<br>item3<br>item4<br>item4";
$pieces = explode("<br>", $html);
print_r($pieces);
```

That would return

```
Array
(
    [0] => item1
    [1] => item2
    [2] => item3
    [3] => item4
    [4] => item5
)
```

In addition, there is a new parameter where you can pass limits....

```
$html = "item1<br>item2<br>item3<br>item4<br>item4";
$pieces = explode("<br>", $html, 2);
print_r($pieces);
```

That would return

```
Array
(
    [0] => item1
    [1] => item2 item3 item4 item5
)
```